# Access 2013 Import Type Conversion Error Handling Blanks

Tags: vba, ms-access, type-conversion, ms-office, import-from-excel

I have an Excel dataset to be imported into Access. One of the fields in Excel has type General, but it's really numbers shown as text. And some of the data in this field is blank. So when importing into Access, I tried to convert this field to double, but due to having blanks in the data, it's giving me type conversion error. Is there a way to handle blanks as 0s and convert to double during the import steps?

Also I think there used to be an "Advanced" button during the import fields step in Access. Now I don't see that button anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my testing, the blank cells are not the issue, it is the cells that are individually formatted to display as text and do have data. Recommend fixing the spreadsheet. review:

[Convert 'numbers as text' to numbers](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T010205_Converting_Forced_Text_to_Numbers.html)

Comment: the excel spreadsheet is a software output, and I'm automating some reports using Access. So I don't want to manipulate the spreadsheet before importing it to Access. Anyway, I've figured out a way which is to run some queries in Access to resolve this. Thanks though